# Dual Norm proof

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $\|.\|$ denote any norm on $C^m$. The corresponding dual norm $\|.\|'$ is defined by the formula  $\|x\|' = sup_{\|y\|=1}|y^*x|$.

(a)Prove that  $\|.\|'$ is a norm?

(b) Let $x, y \in C^m $ with $\|x\|=\|y\|=1$ be given. Show that there exists a rank-one matrix $B=yz^*$ such that $Bx=y$ and $\|B\| =1$, where $\|B\|$ is the matrix norm of B induced by the vector norm   $\|.\| $. You may use the following lemma, without proof: given  $x\in C^m $ there exists a nonzero $z \in C^{m}$ such that $|z^*x|= \|z\|^{'}\|x\|$.

(Form  Numerical linear algebra by Trefethen & Bau , exercise 3.6.b)

I already figured out part a, but for part b I don't know where to start.

My Thinking: 
$B=yz^*$  (we want $Bx=y$ )so I mutliplied both side by x  = > $Bx=yz^{*}x$. I need to  show  $z^{*}x =e_{1}$

Do I approach the problem correctly?
Thank you for any help.

Comment: (in fact $z = Cx$ only if we consider the $\|.\|_2$ norm, if it is the $\|.\|_1$ then $z$ can be found easily too) ($C$ is any constant) and no, why would you consider the identity matrix ?

Comment: note that with $(e_m)$ the canonical basis of $\mathbb{C}^*$, you can identify $z^*$ with the vector $Z_m = z^* e_m$. now you can find the coefficients of the matrix$B$ ? $B_{nm} = \ ?$

Comment: Are you saying that:  $B_{nm}= y_{n1} z^{*}_{1m}$ ?

Comment: are you saying that it works ? (and you need a constant to ensure $\|B\| = 1$)

Comment: I think, $Bx = yz^*x$ has an answer when B is m by m and $z^*$ is 1 by m , since size of both x and y is m by 1. Then $b_ij = y_i \times z_j$ .  
I have two problems:
(1) I don't know how to relate the given lemma to the main question( I assume the $z$s in given lemma and main question are not the same).
(2) when it used $\|.\|$ should I assume  $\|.\|_{2}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to resurrect, but figured this could use an answer.

Don't make any assumptions about $||\cdot||$, beyond those inherent in the definition of a norm.  This proof depends on the axiom $||\alpha z||=|\alpha|\,||z||$ for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ and $z\in\mathbb{C}^m$, for both norms.  The key is to find $z$ such that $z^*x=1$. (Not $e_1$, the dimensions are wrong, and it wouldn't contract with $y$!)

Using the given lemma, take $w\neq0$ such that $|w^*x|=||w||'\,||x||$.  Then take $z=w/x^*w$, so that
$$z^*x=w^*x/w^*x=1.$$
This also gives $|z^*x|=||z||'=1$.

Then immediately, $yz^*x=y$.  Furthermore, $$||yz^*||=\sup_{||x'||=1}||yz^*x'||=||y||\sup_{||x'||=1}|z^*x'|=||y||\,||z||'=1.$$

If someone has a nice proof of the lemma, that would be cool to see.  (The reason I came looking.)

Comment: The lemma is a consequence the Hahn-Banach theorem. Really this whole result is an easy consequence of the Hahn-Banach theorem. By Hahn-Banach, there is a linear functional $\omega$ such that $\omega(x) = 1$ and $\lVert \omega \rVert = 1$.  The linear operator $B$ on $\mathbb{C}^m$ defined by $Bv = \omega(v)y$ has the desired properties.